# ListBox emtpy when bound to populated ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to implement filtering on a `UserControl` (which is essentially just a `ListBox` with a data template) using `ICollectionView`.

When I bind to the `ICollectionView` my `LOAListBox` is empty.

My xaml looks like this:

```xml
<TextBox Text="{Binding SearchString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

<!-- LOA_List is a DependencyProperty which binds to ListBox.ItemsSource -->
<controls:LOAListBox LOA_List="{Binding FilteredView, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

And in my view model, I do this:

```cs
public class LOAViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICollectionView FilteredView { get; private set; }
    
    private string _searchString;
    public string SearchString
    {
        get => _searchString;
        set
        {
            _searchString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SearchString");
            FilteredView.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private List<LOA> _available_LOAs;
    public List<LOA> Available_LOAs
    {
        get => _available_LOAs;
        set
        {
            _available_LOAs = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Available_LOAs");
        }
    }

    public LOAViewModel()
    {
        Available_LOAs = data.GetLOAData();
        FilteredView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Available_LOAs);
        FilteredView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => Filter(o as LOA));
    }

    private bool Filter(LOA loa)
    {
        return SearchString == null || loa.Display_Name.Contains(SearchString);
    }
}
```

During debugging I can see that `Available_LOAs` is not empty and after `GetDefaultView` `FilteredView` also has that same collection. There aren't any binding errors. I also made by filter method always return true just to remove that possibility.

I feel like I must be missing a step but I've checked various other online examples and I can't find anything... My hunch is that it's related to the fact I'm binding to a `ListBox` nested in a `UserControl`, but I don't understand why that would matter when it works if change the binding from `FilteredView` to `Available_LOAs` directly.

Update; this is the simplified code for `LOAListBox`:

XAML:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LOA_List, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"/>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```cs
public partial class LOAListBox : UserControl
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSource = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LOA_List), typeof(List<LOA>), typeof(LOAListBox), new PropertyMetadata());
    public List<LOA> LOA_List
    {
        get => (List<LOA>)GetValue(DataSource);
        set => SetValue(DataSource, value);

    }

}
```

Comment: I've added the code for `LOAListBox`. I've reduced it down to the simplest form, but that's everything that relates to the `ItemsSource` binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going step-by-step to reproduce the issue, I eventually realised that I wasn't notifying of changes to `FilteredView` and, not helping matters, I was changing the `ICollectionView` source without reassigning the `ICollectionView`,

So I made my `FilteredView` a standard property that calls `RaisePropertyChanged()`:

```cs
private ICollectionView _filteredView;
public ICollectionView FilteredView
{
    get => _filteredView;
    set
    {
        _filteredView = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("FilteredView");
    }
}
```

And when I change the `ICollectionView` source variable I reassign based on the new source collection:

```cs
FilteredView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Available_Destination_LOAs);
FilteredView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => Filter(o as LOA));
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bind an `ICollectionView` to a `List<T>` property.

Change the type of your dependency property to `IEnumerable`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSource = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LOA_List), 
    typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(LOAListBox), new PropertyMetadata());
public IEnumerable LOA_List
{
    get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(DataSource);
    set => SetValue(DataSource, value);
}
```

As a side note, you should also change the name of the dependency property from "DataSource" to "LOA_ListProperty" (and remove the underscore from both names) to follow the naming convention.

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't appeared to make any difference. Still the listbox appears empty and no errors of any kind...

Comment: Does the binding to the `SearchString` work? Do you explicitly set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` somewhere?

Comment: The binding to SearchString does work, although in trying to get this working I've just had my filter method always return true just to remove another variable. I set the `DataContext` of the containing view as the `ExpiredLOAViewModel` (via a `ViewModelLocator`) and the `LOAListBox` UserControl doesn't explicitly set a datacontext.

Comment: Well, you need to provide a repo if you want any further help. Chaning the type of the property to the non-generic `IEnumerable` should work. It does for me.

Comment: I'm going to try setting up a separate project and build towards what I currently have and see where it breaks down... I'll report back.